# Ошибки при создании пустой процедуры

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

Хочу создать пустую процедуру. Но никак не получается:

```
create or replace procedure myproc () as
begin
    select * from table
end;
```

Получаю ошибки:

```
1/19      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    current delete exists prior   
4/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     (
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите действительно пустую процедуру, ругаться прекратит:

```
create or replace procedure myemptyproc as
begin
    null;
end;
/

Procedure MYEMPTYPROC compiled
```

Далее, изменяйте её. При изменении процедуры стоит пользоваться [синтактическими диаграмами](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54) из документации, а также другими достовернымии источниками.
Не полагайтесь на чувство: "Это вроде как-то так", результат будет предопределён, как сейчас в вопросе в 4-х строчках 4-е синтактические ошибки.